# How can I split a table into several parts with a limit number of rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with Postgresql, using Datagrip. I have generated a table with 5 million rows. However, this table will be used in another task which requires a maximum of 100000 rows. Is there a way I can split this dataset into several others with the maximum number of rows being 100000? It can be tables of 50000, I don't care. The only thing is that the maximum should be 100000.

I thought this would be simple to find, but googled and I was led to some topics that are not really what I need, such as

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66552/split-a-very-large-sql-table-to-multiple-smaller-tables
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151604/how-to-split-table-into-two-tables-in-one-transaction-or-query
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164728/postgresql-splitting-one-table-into-three-and-setting-up-references-between-them.

Comment: Can you generate 5 million rows again? and how you inserting them into db?

Comment: How you are using them? selecting one at once or selecting all 5kk rows? asking because you may choose many ways to chunk your table into several. Why 100k rows?

Comment: @AzizUmarov it's just a select * from table (with a few where's and if's).

Comment: Why not use views?

Comment: How can I do that in datagrip? does that work for exporting in CSVs?